# Ordenação de array com heapsort simulando árvore de múltiplos filhos

Tags: desempenho, classificação, complexidade-de-algoritmo

**Dúvida:**

Para ordenar arrays com heapsort, costuma-se simular neles árvores com até dois filhos por pai, não mais. Minha dúvida é se há estudos, implementações, experimentos, relatórios, dados acessíveis que investigam o desempenho do heapsort em arrays simulando árvores com números maiores de filhos por pai.

**Detalhes:**

Eu implementei a ordenação de array com heapsort usando o máximo de dois filhos por pai. Com as noções de complexidade de código que tenho, me pareceu que o número de comparações de uma interação do heapsort (definição do último elemento do subarray atual) fica, no pior caso, em torno de `2*log2(n)`, pois são duas comparações por nível de profundidade e a profundidade fica em torno de `log2(n)`. Mas e se eu "adotasse mais filhos"?

Pensando nisso, suponho que possamos adaptar o código para mais de dois filhos adicionando, para cada filho adicional, uma comparação por nível de profundidade. Aumenta as comparações por profundidade, mas a profundidade diminui, assim talvez realizando menos comparações. A fórmula que encontrei para estimar as comparações por interação dependendo do número `F` de filhos é `F*logF(n)`.

Se eu estiver certo, matematicamente o ideal seria `F = e ~ 2.71828`, mas não dá. Aumentar de dois filhos para três filhos diminuiria o número de comparações (`-5,36%` em `F=3`). Aumentar de dois para quatro filhos, conservaria (`0,00%` em `F=4`). Aumentar de dois para cinco filhos ou mais aumentariam as comparações (`+7,67%` se `F=5`). Enfim, matematicamente é assim, mas como é o desempenho na prática? Já se testou isso? Há dados conhecidos?

Comment: A grosso modo, a adoção de um filho a mais faria com que se multiplicasse por um termo constante a complexidade assintótica, portanto estaria dentro da mesma classe de complexidade temporal. Tempo de execução real, porém, já não sei.

Comment: Exatamente. Assintoticamente, nada muda. Quero saber como é na prática. Talvez eu mesmo tenha que experimentar. Não acho nada na internet.

Comment: eu fiz um repositório em Java para testar algoritmos de ordenação, quer incluir lá?

Comment: Ok, eu olho. Obrigado.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/totalcross/stack-overflow/tree/master/performance-ordenacao;  no caso, heapsort não estava no escopo original. Se conseguir fazer o heap ternário, vai ser uma ótima contribuição

Comment: Certo. Na verdade, implementei em C++, mas posso converter para java se eu conseguir implementar direito.

Comment: `O(log3(n))` e `O(log2(n))` são assintoticamente equivalentes. Que de certa forma estou a dizer o que o @JeffersonQuesado disse mas de outra forma.

Comment: Sei... log3(n)=0,63093*log2(n)... portanto para n>1 tem 0,63092*log2(n)<log3(n)<0,63094*log2(n)... logo log3(n)=THETA(log2(n)), etc etc etc. E o resultado prático da mudança na implementação, fora do campo da análise assintótica?

Comment: Fazendo as duas parte da mesma classe temporal então só vai fazer diferença para um N bem baixo. O que significa que o ganho não é significativo para tão poucas operações

Comment: Mesmo um algoritmo 10%, 5%, 3%, mesmo nem 1% mais rápido é mais eficiente. Refiná-lo pode adicionar mais percentuais e chegar a algo muito bacana. Quero saber mais sobre isso.

Comment: @RHERWOLF , alguma novidade? Conseguiu fazer e obter os resultados de performance?

Comment: Consegui implementar, não tem dado erro... mas não consegui fazer as medidas. As diferenças de resultados não cobrem os erros de medição. Preciso de maior precisão. Também gostaria de um meio de desenvolver arrays no pior caso do heapsort e outros algoritmos para compará-los, mesmo assintoticamente insignificante.